# Copying Word doc using FileStream corrupts doc

Tags: c#, wcf, ms-word

I am writing a WCF service that transfers large files using byte buffers. I am having a problem with Word docx. I can copy the file but when I open it I get a "file corrupt" error and then it asks me if I want to salvage it. If I say "yes" it salvages it fine.

How do I copy a word doc? I've tried changing the encoding and everything I can find on the 'net, nothing is helping.

Here's my client:

```
FileInfo SourceFile = new FileInfo(textBoxPath.Text);
LargeFileContractClient localClient = new LargeFileContractClient();

LargeFileInfo LocalLargeFileInfo = new LargeFileInfo();
LocalLargeFileInfo.TransactionID = Guid.NewGuid();
LocalLargeFileInfo.FileName = SourceFile.Name;

LargeFileInfo localLargeFileResponse = new LargeFileInfo();

using (BinaryReader SourceStream = new BinaryReader(File.Open(SourceFile.FullName, FileMode.Open), Encoding.Unicode))
{
   while (SourceStream.BaseStream.Position < SourceStream.BaseStream.Length)
   {
       //Get a set of bytes and pack them into the largefileinfo
       int BytesRead = SourceStream.Read(FileBuffer, 0, 1000);

       LocalLargeFileInfo.FileContent = FileBuffer;

       //Send the LargeFileInfo to the server
       localLargeFileResponse = localClient.TransferLargeFile(LocalLargeFileInfo);

   }
}
```

...and my server code:

```
public LargeFileInfo TransferLargeFile(LargeFileInfo argFileInfo)
{
   FileInfo DestFile = new FileInfo(String.Format(@"C:\LargeFiles\{0}\{1}", argFileInfo.TransactionID, argFileInfo.FileName));

   if(!DestFile.Directory.Exists)
   {
       DestFile.Directory.Create();
   }

   using (BinaryWriter DestStream = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream (DestFile.FullName, FileMode.Append), Encoding.Unicode))
   {
       DestStream.Write(argFileInfo.FileContent, 0, argFileInfo.FileContent.Length);
   }

   argFileInfo.ContinueFrom += argFileInfo.FileContent.Length;

   return argFileInfo;
}
```

I've tried changing the encoding. I've tried using plain file stream. I've tried everything I can think of and I cannot get the file at the end to open.

I can copy zips and AutoCAD dwg and PDFs but not Word docs. What is so special about them?

Comment: Have you checked to make sure there isn't any data there to begin with? You are using `FileMode.Append` (I assume so you can transfer the file in multiple chunks) but I don't see a check to make sure you're not creating a junk file by appending to something that already exists.

Comment: I missed the part where I create a new directory based on the GUID passed in. So, no, there's no file there.

Comment: What's confusing me is that a .docx actually IS a special form of a .zip. You can change the extension and open it up as a .zip. Perhaps try turning it into a .zip, transferring it, and then rename it back as a .docx? That would make sure the issue isn't in the filename, although it is a long shot.

Comment: Wait, you're using a `BinaryReader`. That's meant for primitive types. Try using `File.ReadAllBytes` instead: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx (or `File.OpenRead` if you're doing this in chunks)

Comment: BinaryReader is just the most recent incantation. I've tried File.OpenRead() and it does the same thing. I am going to try the zip suggestion and see what happens with that.

Comment: Renaming it does not help but I did notice that the file sizes are different. The source file is 801,876 bytes and the destination file is 802000 bytes. This makes me think that the writer is writing the extra bytes that are rounding out the byte array. Let me take care of that and report back.

Comment: That was it!! I wasn't resizing the array for the end of file and the service would just add the extra zeros. I changed the code to use Array.Copy to get the actual number of bytes that were read and it works fine. Thanks for the poke.

Comment: Please take the time to properly format your code. You can preview it in a WYSIWYG fashion immediately below as you're typing it, and can make any corrections before posting. (If you make a mistake, you can edit to fix it.) If we can clearly read your question and code, it makes it more likely you'll get an answer. Thanks. :-)